# Amortization with skipped payments

Tags: finance

Amortization is usually calculated with the formula

[image: where P is the loan,R is the monthly payment,r is the percent where it is compounded,and m is the compounding factor or rate of compounding and t is time in years]

And if graphed in excel[image: a loan of 2,500,000 2% compounded annually with a monthly payment of 278316.32 will be fully paid in 10 years]

So my question is how would it be to solve for the payment of the 10th payment or year if in the presented sheet, the eighth and ninth monthly payment would be skipped and the payment for the tenth year would still be able to pay off the loan.

[image: tripling the payment in the tenth year to compensate the 2 missed payments still won't pay the loan]

How do you solve for the exact value of the payment in the tenth year?Will there be a change in formula?how ?

Comment: P is loan,R is the monthly payment,r is the percent it is compounded,m is the rate it is compounded,it may be annually(1),bi annually(2) quarter

Comment: (4),or monthly(12) and t is time in years

Comment: And the first presented sheet is with a loan of 2,500,000 to be fully paid in 10 years compounded 2 percent annually within a time of ten years

Comment: As you can see in the third sheet,tripling the tenth payment will not exactly pay off the loan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite follow your notation, but if $A$ is your calculated periodic payment amount and you miss two payments, then the catch-up payment should be not $3A$ but perhaps $$A(1+i)^2+ A(1+i)+A= (3+3i+i^2)A$$ where $i$ is the effective interest rate per period.

Comment: Hm how were you able to arrive on that solution?

Comment: The first missed payment needs two dollops of interest (compounded), while the second needs one, and the third is on time

Comment: In the problem,is the effective rate of interest is 2%?

Comment: Also thank you for this.it works!